# Android OpenGL 3x3 Matrix to Quaternion

Tags: android, opengl-es, matrix, quaternions

I want to rotate a 3D cube using a 3x3 matrix. I manage to get the matrix but OpenGL needs a quaternion to rotate the cube using

glRotatef (float angle, float x, float y, float z);

How can I go from a 3x3 matrix to a quaternion to use this method properly ?

Thanks!

Comment: `glRotatef` does *not* take a quaternion. Also, you don't need to use `glRotatef` if you have a matrix; `glMultMatrix` will work if you already have a matrix (though you'll need to make it 4x4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glRotatef` doesn't expect a quaternion, but an axis and angle (in degrees). Have a look at:

http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToAngle/index.htm

Answer (score -1):

[See Here](http://jsperf.com/conversion-of-3x3-matrix-to-quaternion) to see how it is done in javascript. The method is the same, it converts a 3x3 matrix into a quaternion, just convert the code to java and away you go.

Comment: I didnt get it to work yet but it helped me a lot !! Thank you